# Error 1219 occurs when I try to map a network drive multiple server 

Tags: network-drive, net-use

I have a network drive (for instance, G: on Server A). And I am trying to map an additional network drive (H:) to a new server (Server B). I tried the `net use` command, giving to rise to error 1219 on Window XP.

```
net use h: \\ServerB\docs /user:ServerB\user Password
```

I am connecting the network drive of Server A using Server A's account. And I have to use both of network drive simultaeusly, so I don't think I can the `net use * /del` command to connect to Server B.

What can I do?

Comment: did you tried **net use**?

Answer (score 9):

Any util commands:

**net use (to see all existing connections)**

**net use * /del /yes (to delete all existing connections)**

**Script**

```
@echo off

set "svrname=server"
set "share=share$"
set "usr=administrator"
set "pwd=password"

for /f "tokens=2" %%# in ('net use^|find /i "\\%svrname%"') do net use %%# /delete>nul

net use l: \\%svrname%\%share% /user:%usr% "%pwd%">nul
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use the server IP address instead of the DNS name, it gets around this silly Windows limitation.

So instead of

```
net use h: \\ServerB\docs /user:ServerB\user Password
```

If 'Server' has an IP address of 192.168.0.1 you can use

```
net use h: \\192.168.0.1\docs /user:ServerB\user Password
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This was the only option that worked for me, the solution from Kiquenet gave the same error 1219 for me